# Windows Applications for Exploit Development exercising?

Tags: windows, vulnerability, exploit-development

I started to learn ASM and learned a lot about exploit development in the last few weeks. My question is, are there any comparable vulnerable windows programs like vulnserver out there which are good for exercising ?

Comment: http://opensecuritytraining.info/Exploits2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a very comprehensive list](https://www.amanhardikar.com/mindmaps/Practice.html) of various applications to use for pentesting. There isn't much I could find however for **windows applications**, but here's some of them from the link above:

- www.oldapps.com - Some old versions of apps which have known vulnerabilities.
- www.payatu.com/hacksys-extreme-vulnerable-driver - A windows driver with vulnerabilities such as stack overflow.
- sourceforge.net/projects/virtualhacking/files/apps%40realworld/ - This website has a TON of vulnerable applications all ready to be exploited.
- www.oldversion.com/ - More older versions of programs.
- www.overthewire.org - This has many security challenges - buffer overflows, web exploitation, etc.

The website I linked earlier also has many other resources for practising which may interest you.